# the definition of autocorrelation

Tags: probability-theory

I find the definition of autocorrelation from wiki:
$$
R(s,t)=\frac{E\left[ \left( {{X}_{t}}-{{\mu }_{t}} \right)\left( {{X}_{s}}-{{\mu }_{s}} \right) \right]}{{{\sigma }_{t}}{{\sigma }_{s}}}
$$
But I also find the definition of autocorrelation as below somewhere:
$$
R(s,t)=E\left[ X(s)X(t) \right]
$$

Are these two definitions equal? Can anyone provide the proof?

Comment: Where is 'somewhere'?

Comment: The definition of autocorrelation in statistics is different from in signal processing, how to understand the sentence "In signal processing, the above definition is often used without the normalization, that is, without subtracting the mean and dividing by the variance. When the autocorrelation function is normalized by mean and variance, it is sometimes referred to as the autocorrelation coefficient." I quote it from the wiki. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Signal_processing

Answer (score 2):

The bottom definition is the one I often use, i.e. without subtracting the mean and without normalizing. When you take the expectation with the mean subtracted it is often termed the *Autocovariance*, i.e.:

$C_{xx}(\tau) = E[(x(t)-\mu)(x(t+\tau)-\mu)]$

Having said that both definitions you provide get (confusingly) used, depending on the field of application. But just to make it clear they are *not* equivalent.

Comment: This is quite misleading: one always subtract the mean, whether for autocorrelation or auto covariance, but the autocorrelation is the autocovariance normalized by the standard deviations.

Comment: @Did, it's not misleading. You do not always subtract the mean. There are two commonly used definitions of auto correlation. Read the wiki page for reference.

Comment: Right. (And the modified version of your answer is clearer, at least to me. +1.)

Answer (score -1):

The first definition is the true definition for the autocorrelation.

The second equation you got from "somewhere" just looks like the autocorrelation function for a Gaussian R.V. with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2= 1.$